# How to write where clause to consider the earlier date given 2 dates?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2019

Control table:

ControlID, Date1, Date2, Date3

Sale table:

ID, ControlID, SaleDate

I want to get the sales from Date1 to which ever date is earlier amongst Date2 and Date3.

```
SELECT *
FROM SALE S
JOIN CONTROL C ON S.CONTROLID=C.ID
WHERE S.SALEDATE>=C.DATE1 AND S.SALEDATE<EARLIER(DATE2, DATE3)
```

What is the correct way to write the `EARLIER(DATE2, DATE3)` logic? For example - implement this as a new scalar function?

Or maybe:

```
AND S.SALEDATE<C.DATE2 AND S.SALEDATE<C.DATE3
```

Comment: just use a `case` expression to return the earlier date

Answer (score 1):

[LEAST](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/logical-functions-least-transact-sql?view=azure-sqldw-latest) may be available to you (SQL Server 2022)

```
SELECT *
FROM SALE S
JOIN CONTROL C ON S.CONTROLID=C.ID
WHERE S.SALEDATE>=C.DATE1 AND S.SALEDATE<LEAST(DATE2, DATE3)
```

otherwise try

```
WHERE S.SALEDATE>=C.DATE1 AND S.SALEDATE< DATE2 AND S.SALEDATE< DATE3
```

Comment: `LEAST` isn't working with sql server 2019. How about `AND S.SALEDATE<C.DATE2 AND S.SALEDATE<C.DATE3`?

Answer (score 1):

In order to be able to SARG saledate, I'd use a case:

```
WHERE S.SALEDATE>=C.DATE1 
AND S.SALEDATE< CASE WHEN DATE2<DATE3 THEN DATE2 ELSE DATE3 END
```

An alternative which is probably less performant but arguably easier to read (and capable of accepting more values) is to make a "mini" unpivoted subquery:

```
WHERE S.SALEDATE>=C.DATE1 
AND S.SALEDATE< (select min(datex) from (values (date2),(date3)) as t1(datex))
```

---

Post comment addendum:

If you have one less_than condition and one greater_than condition, an index can be used once to satisfy both. For ease's sake, let's say your dates are integers (they actually are anyway). Let's say date1=5, date2=20, date3=17.

If you use my `case` solution (or you are lucky enough to be able to use `earlier`), then the engine will:

1. Calculate *once* that starting point is date1=5 and ending point= case/earlier(20,17)=17
2. If there is an index on sale.saledate, it will index seek to 5 and 17. This could be very fast if [sale] is a large table.
3. Now that it quickly found the starting and ending point, it returns all possible rows on the output/next operator

If you use `AND S.SALEDATE<C.DATE2 AND S.SALEDATE<C.DATE3`, what probably will happen is that it will start fastly on 5 like before, but then create an expression aliased somewhat like expr01 which includes both of these conditions. It will then evaluate this expr01 beginning at 5 and stopping not at 17, but at the end of the table.

This *does* have some speculation on my part, that's why it would be helpful for you to run both and then pastetheplan.com.

Note: It is highly probable that either 1) such an index does not exist, or 2) the optimizer wouldn't use it, or 3) your query is fast anyway, which makes all this analysis partly a waste of time, much like [XKCD](https://xkcd.com/1445) suggests:

[image: https://xkcd.com/1445]

However, even in these cases, understanding the points and creating a good programming habit of SARGable queries is just good business.

Comment: How about `AND S.SALEDATE<C.DATE2 AND S.SALEDATE<C.DATE3`?

Comment: Not as good. By forcing two conditions, you are probably disallowing the use of the index, or at best, you are using it twice. Of course, if you think it is the clearest version, and it runs fast enough, it is also OK. It would be interesting to post the execution plans for all those alternatives at pastetheplan.com

Comment: Based on the 2 examples you have given in your answer, then index on SaleDate will anyways be used twice - once for Date1 and then 2nd time for CASE. In my example from the above comment it will be used thrice - is that what you are implying please?

Comment: I'll append an explanation to the answer